# Get large string without catastrophic backtracking regex

Tags: git, git-diff, probot

I'm wanting to use Regex to get a specific file (e.g. package-lock.json) out of a git diff. The reason for this approach is because I'm getting a whole git diff via the Github API (Using Octocat js), therefore I can't just run the git diff on that specific file. (As far as I'm aware). Obviously the diff on a file like `package-lock.json` is very large so there's a lot of content). What I've noticed is that when I try to use a regular expression to get this content out it fails due to catastrophic backtracking.

Essentially the file structure looks like this

```
diff --git a/package-lock.json b/package-lock.json
lots of content

diff --git a/next-file b/next-file
```

Therefore my idea was to get everything between the two `diff --git` strings.

I figured I could just use this `/(?<=diff --git )(.+?)(?=diff)/gs` This works fine if the lookahead is not too far ahead, but after a long way through the file this stops working due to catastrophic backtracking.

I get why this is happening but just don't get how to get around it. Perhaps I should be sorting this some other way and just using Regex for more specific details?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Taking @Andy's lead, this is a good application of Perl's and Ruby's rather obscure [flip-flop operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(programming)). In Ruby this would be written `s1 = "diff --git a/package-lock.json b/package-lock.json"; s2 = "diff --git a/next-file b/next-file"; arr.select { |line| true if line == s1 .. line == s2 }[1..-2]`, where `arr` is an array of strings. `[1..-2]` removes the first and last lines of the array that is returned, which are `s1` and `s2` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working with lines of data, and regexes don't work well like that, as you've found out.  Use a tool like `awk` that can find ranges of lines.

Give this file foo.txt:

```
Here is stuff I don't care about
diff --git a/package-lock.json b/package-lock.json
lots of content

diff --git a/next-file b/next-file
Don't care about this either.
```

use awk to specify a range of lines you want to print:

```
$ awk '/^diff --git a\/package-lock/,/^diff --git a\/next-file/' foo.txt
diff --git a/package-lock.json b/package-lock.json
lots of content

diff --git a/next-file b/next-file
```